# Replace javascript with a local file

Tags: javascript, web

If I don't have access to the development environment, then I want to have the opportunity to change front-end code on the fly by edit / replace / change javascript files. What I want is to just use the default webpage and just replace a javascript file with a local version.

I've tried adding javascript with this kind of code, with firebug:

```
$.getScript("mobile.js", function(){
    alert("Running test.js");
});
```

but how do I replace it with a local file?

I think this is possible with the tool "espresso" (mac users) .. any Windows alternative?

Comment: What exactly are you looking to achieve?

Comment: Espresso is just a web IDE. Are you asking if there are HTML/JS/CSS IDEs for Windows?

Comment: I want to change the page on the fly. If I do not have access to the development environment, then I have the opportunity to change front-end code on the fly by edit / replace / change javascript file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) for this sort of thing. If you just want to replace one script with another, you can use the Map Local feature to remap a URL to a local file.

Comment: It works like a charm! Is it possible to add additional new local scripts when loading a webpage?

Comment: The Rewrite feature lets you run a regular expression over the response body. That could add a new `<script>` tag.